# How can I swap numbers inside data block of repeating format using linux commands?

Tags: linux, replace, awk, sed

I have a huge data file, and I hope to swap some numbers of 2nd column only, in the following format file. The file have 25,000,000 dataset, and 8768 lines each.

%% Edited: shorter 10 line example. Sorry for the inconvenience. This is typical one data block.

```
# Dataset 1  
# 
# Number of lines 10 
# 
# header lines
 5 11 3 10 120 90 0         0.952         0.881         0.898         2.744         0.034         0.030
 10 12 3 5 125 112 0         0.952         0.897         0.905         2.775         0.026         0.030
 50 10 3 48 129 120 0         1.061         0.977         0.965         3.063         0.001         0.026
 120 2 4 5 50 186 193 0         0.881         0.965         0.899         0.917         3.669         0.000        -0.005
 125 3 4 10 43 186 183 0         0.897         0.945         0.910         0.883         3.641         0.000         0.003
 186 5 4 120 125 249 280 0         0.899         0.910         0.931         0.961         3.727         0.000        -0.001
 193 6 4 120 275 118 268 0         0.917         0.895         0.897         0.937         3.799         0.000         0.023
 201 8 4 278 129 131 280 0         0.921         0.837         0.870         0.934         3.572         0.000         0.008
 249 9 4 186 355 179 317 0         0.931         0.844         0.907         0.928         3.615         0.000         0.008
 280 10 4 186 201 340 359 0         0.961         0.934         0.904         0.898         3.700         0.000         0.033
#
# Dataset 1  
# 
# Number of lines 10 
...
```

As you can see, there are 7 repeating header lines in the head, and 1 trailing line at the end of the dataset. Those header and trailing lines are all beginning from #. As a result, the data will have 7 header lines, 8768 data lines, and 1 trailing line, total 8776 lines per a data block. That one trailing line only contains sinlge '#'.

I want to swap some numbers in 2nd columns only. First, I want to replace

```
1, 9, 10, 11 => 666
2, 6, 7, 8 => 333
3, 4, 5 => 222
```

of the 2nd column, and then,

```
666 => 6
333 => 3
222 => 2
```

of the 2nd column. I hope to conduct this replacing for all repeating dataset.

I tried this with python, but the data is too big, so it makes memory error. How can I perform this swapping with linux commands like sed or awk or cat commands?

Thanks

Best,

Comment: @EdMorton I have enough disk space, so making temp file is ok. Python had hard time to temporarily store large data...

Comment: @EdMorton Could you just teach me how can I replace some numbers only in 2nd column with sed, inside that format? If not sed, awk or cat is also fine.

Comment: If I understand you, you want a `2` in column 2 to become a `3` eventually?  Why do you think you need an intermediate step where a `2` first becomes a `333`?  Are you looking to double your datasets, or manipulate the data somehow based on that?

Comment: @n0741337 Yes, exactly. 

Reason for intermediate step is, I don't know how to differentiate them. For example, if I directly change '1, 9, 10, 11' to '6', then those swapped '6' will become 3 in the next swapping (2, 6, 7, 8 to 3). This will cause 1, 9, 10, 11, 2, 6, 7, 8 swapped to 3, which is not the result I want. I don't know how to escape from this.

Comment: @EdMorton I reduced the size of example.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry, I updated the example. Is that enough for you? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, but you'd have to use GNU awk, as it's using the `gensub` command and `$0` reassignment.

Put the following into an executable awk file ( like `script.awk` ):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    a[1] = a[9] = a[10] = a[11] = 6
    a[2] = a[6] = a[7]  = a[8]  = 3
    a[3] = a[4] = a[5]          = 2
}

function swap( c2,            val ) {
    val = a[c2]
    return( val=="" ? c2 : val )
}

/^( [0-9]+ )/ { $0 = gensub( /^( [0-9]+)( [0-9]+)/, "\\1 " swap($2), 1 ) }

47 # print the line
```

Here's the breakdown:

- `BEGIN` - set up an array `a` with mappings of the new values.
- create a user defined function `swap` to provide values for the 2nd column from the `a` array or the value itself.  The `c2` element is passed in, while the `val` element is a local variable ( becuase no 2nd argument is passed in ).
- when a line starts with a space followed by a number and a space (the pattern), then use `gensub` to replace the first occurrance of the first number pattern with itself concatenated with a space and the return from `swap`(the action).  In this case, I'm using gensub's replacement text to preserve the first column data.  The second column is passed to `swap` using the field data identifier of `$2`.  Using `gensub` should preserve the formatting of the data lines.
- `47` - an expression that evaluates to true provides the default action of printing `$0`, which for data lines might have been modified.  Any line that wasn't "data" will be printed out here w/o modifications.

The provided data doesn't show all the cases, so I made up my own test file:

```
# 2 skip me
9 2 not going to process me
 1 1 don't              change the for  matting
 2 2    4       23242.223       data
 3 3 data       that's  formatted
 4 4 7  that's  formatted
 5 5 data       that's  formatted
 6 6 data       that's  formatted
 7 7 data       that's  formatted
 8 8 data       that's  formatted
 9 9 data       that's  formatted
 10 10 data     that's  formatted
 11 11 data     that's  formatted
 12 12 data     that's  formatted
 13 13 data     that's  formatted
 14 s data      that's  formatted
# some other data
```

Running the executable awk (like `./script.awk data`) gives the following output:

```
# 2 skip me
9 2 not going to process me
 1 6 don't              change the for  matting
 2 3    4       23242.223       data
 3 2 data       that's  formatted
 4 2 7  that's  formatted
 5 2 data       that's  formatted
 6 3 data       that's  formatted
 7 3 data       that's  formatted
 8 3 data       that's  formatted
 9 6 data       that's  formatted
 10 6 data      that's  formatted
 11 6 data      that's  formatted
 12 12 data     that's  formatted
 13 13 data     that's  formatted
 14 s data      that's  formatted
# some other data
```

which looks alright to me, but I'm not the one with 25 million datasets.

You'd also most definitely want to try this on a smaller sample of your data first (the first few datasets?) and redirect stdout a temp file perhaps like:

```
head -n 26328 data | ./script.awk - > tempfile
```

You can learn more about the elements used in this script here:

- [awk basics (the man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)
- [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Basics)
- [User defined functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002ddefined)
- [String functions - gensub()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions)

And of course, you should spend some quality time reviewing awk related questions and answers on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm surprised about the way how you escape from intermediate step. I think I really need to learn gnu awk. I'm currently testing this with that big data.

Comment: May I have questions?  1) Does 'c2' in the function automatically recognize 2nd column? If it is, then c1 or c10 is first and 10th column?    2) That way of "mapping" is gnu-awk's way? Is this replace?    3) I'm still learning unix commands, but lost track to follow the logic of gensub line. I think that is how you preserved all other data, and header/trailing # lines. Is this right? If possible, could you briefly explain that line?   4) Where can I learn about gnuawk's way to deal with big-data analysis like this example?

Comment: It worked with the big data. Thank you very much again. I really wish to learn a bit more detail of this code. The way of replacing, function swap, and line of 'gensub'. Could you give me a brief explanation or link that I can learn about those commands? Thank you.

Comment: @exsonic01 - the reason awk can be good at dealing with large files here because only one line (record) of the file at a time is "in memory" ( well really it's probably buffering ).  You have several broad questions and I've tried to add some more details, but I would suggest reading a bit from each of the links I've added and then re-reading my answer.